# HTML and CSS: an element is 'pushed' below the container

Tags: html, css, button

I am working with css and html to modify the GUI of an operational tool called OpsWeb.
I added 4 buttons in the center of the top container, but this leads to the right buttons (dropdown menu to select the timeline, button for configuration editor and button for help) to be displayed below the container, causing a sub-optimal visualization.

[Here is the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IViAr.png).

I am trying to modify the css to solve the issue, but with no success so far.

My HTML is:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-schedule">
        ...
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-left" role="group" aria-label="nav-buttons">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default navbar-btn" id="btnNow"
             ...
      </button>
      <button type="button" class="btn navbar-btn" id="btnLive"
        ...
      </button>
      <button type="button" class="btn navbar-btn btn-default" id="btnSim"
       ...
      </button>
      <button type="button" class="btn navbar-btn" id="btnEdit"
        ...
      </button>
    </div>


 <div class="navbar-center">
        4 buttons 
     </div>

    <div class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">

      <mat-form-field id="configuration-selector">
       ...
      </mat-form-field>
     ...
     2 buttons
    ...
 </div>
  </div>
</nav>

<div #gantt id="gantt-container"></div>>
```

The CSS is the following:

```
#edit-config-btn {
  cursor: pointer;
}

#configuration-selector {
  margin-right: 15px;
}

.gantt {
  margin-top: -5px;
  display: inline-block;
}

#gantt-container {
  border: 1px solid gray;
}

.navbar-schedule {
  font-size: 15px;
  background-color: #CFD8DC;
  border-width: 0;
  border-style: none;
  border-radius: 0;
  margin-left: -15px;
  margin-right: -15px;
  height: 3.5em;
  min-height: 3.5em;
}

.navbar-schedule .navbar-left {
  height: 3.5em;
}

.navbar-schedule .navbar-center {
  height: 3.5em;
  margin-left: 50em;
}

.navbar-schedule .navbar-right {
  height: 3.5em;
}
.navbar-schedule .navbar-form {
  height: 3em;
  margin-top: 0.25em;
  margin-bottom: 0.25em;
  margin-left:15px;
}

.navbar-schedule .navbar-nav {
  height: 3.5em;
}

.navbar-schedule .navbar-nav a{
  line-height: 1em;
  height: 3.5em;
  padding-top: 1.25em;
  padding-bottom: 1.25em;
}

and other non related parts.
```

The problem is probably in some kind of conflict arising whenever the central buttons are added, but can't understand why.

Thank you!

Comment: Could you also add the CSS rules for `.container-fluid`?

Answer (score 0):

How about using a grid with 3 columns to place your left, middle and right navigation?

```css
.navbar {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 30% 35% 30%;
}

.navbar  .navbar-left {
  grid-column: 1;
}

.navbar .navbar-center {
  grid-column: 2;
}

.navbar .navbar-right {
  grid-column: 3;
}

#edit-config-btn {
  cursor: pointer;
}

#configuration-selector {
  margin-right: 15px;
}

.gantt {
  margin-top: -5px;
  display: inline-block;
}

#gantt-container {
  border: 1px solid gray;
}

.navbar-schedule {
  font-size: 15px;
  background-color: #cfd8dc;
  border-width: 0;
  border-style: none;
  border-radius: 0;
  height: 3.5em;
  min-height: 3.5em;
}

.navbar-schedule .navbar-center {
  text-align: center;
}

.navbar-schedule .navbar-right {
  text-align: right;
}
.navbar-schedule .navbar-form {
  height: 3em;
  margin-top: 0.25em;
  margin-bottom: 0.25em;
  margin-left: 15px;
}

.navbar-schedule .navbar-nav {
  height: 3.5em;
}

.navbar div .navbar-item {
  height: 3.5em;
  line-height: 3.5em;
}

.navbar-schedule .navbar-nav a {
  line-height: 1em;
  height: 3.5em;
  padding-top: 1.25em;
  padding-bottom: 1.25em;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-schedule">
    <div class="navbar-left navbar-item" role="group" aria-label="nav-buttons">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default navbar-btn" id="btnNow"> ... </button>
      <button type="button" class="btn navbar-btn" id="btnLive">... </button>
      <button type="button" class="btn navbar-btn btn-default" id="btnSim">... </button>
      <button type="button" class="btn navbar-btn" id="btnEdit">... </button>
    </div>

    <div class="navbar-center navbar-item">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default navbar-btn" id="btnNow">1</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn navbar-btn" id="btnLive">2</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn navbar-btn btn-default" id="btnSim">3</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn navbar-btn" id="btnEdit">4</button>
    </div>

    <div class="navbar-item navbar-right">
        <mat-form-field id="configuration-selector">
          ...
        </mat-form-field>
        <select>
          <option>Some value</option>
        </select>
        <button>Test</button>
        <button>Help</button>
      </div>
</nav>

<div #gantt id="gantt-container"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer!
Actually adding the style config for container-fluid created further problems, since it is probably defined in another code that should not be modified.
I tried to apply the grid-technique to the navbar-schedule class, but the output is worst, since now even the central buttons exit the container.

Comment: Then get rid of the `<div class "container-fluid">` and only use the `<nav>...</nav>` and `<div class="navbar-item ...">...</div>` containers. I just updated my above code to mirror the recommended change.